# How to use rfs in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, responsive, postcss

I want to import [rfs](https://github.com/twbs/rfs) and use it in my reactjs app which is created using create-react-app. I have installed rfs, however i don't know how to import it in react. how can I import it as a postcss plugin in react?

Answer (score -1):

Use CSS like below:

```
className{
    font-size: calc(2rem + 1.5vw);
}
```

Hopefully, it will work.